# How to find latest or last element value from array object using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to find latest/last element value from the array object based on condition using jQuery. Each array object contains multiple items. Like Array(0) object contains multiple item with value, Array(1) also contains multiple item with value.....Array(2)...etc.

For example-

```
Array(0) object has items Name:Ravi ,VisitingDate:20/07/2021.
Array(1) object has items Name:Ravi ,VisitingDate:15/08/2021.
Array(2) object has items Name:Ravi ,VisitingDate:30/09/2021 .
```

I want to return latest or last visitingDate value as 30/09/2021 whose name is Ravi using JQuery.

I have tried below JQuery. But it always return first element from array for VisitingDate value as 20/07/2021 which is wrong. It should return last/latest element(VisitingDate) value from array.

```html
if (arryObj.find((o) => { return o["Name"] === "Ravi" }) !== undefined)
 {                        
var VisitDate = arryObj.find((o) => { return  o["Name"] === "Ravi" }).VisitingDate
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please try to enter sample data and expected output too. It helps us. Kudos on adding your attempt.

Comment: Which part of your code specifies that the latest date should be returned?

Comment: I have entered example and my expected result in my question description.

Comment: Inside if condition there is a code which is having VisitingDate. This should return the latest VisitingDateas 30/09/2021 instead of first VisitingDate value as per my example in above .var VisitDate = arryObj.find((o) => { return  o["Name"] === "Ravi" }).VisitingDate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use filter:

```js
let array = [];
    array.push({
        'Name':'Ravi',
        'VisitingDate': '20 / 07 / 2021',
    });
    array.push({
        'Name': 'Ravi',
        'VisitingDate': '20 / 07 / 2021',
    });
    array.push({
        'Name': 'Ravi',
        'VisitingDate': '12 / 09 / 2021',
    });
let last_element = array.filter(function (ar) { return ar.Name == 'Ravi' }).at(-1);
console.log(last_element);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
```